# Expanding a data frame with a column that adds no information

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I've got a data like below:

```
ex <- structure(list(data = structure(c(16983, 16983, 16983, 16983, 
16983, 16983, 16983, 16983, 16983, 16983, 16983, 16983, 16983, 
16983, 16983, 16983, 16983, 16983, 16983, 16984, 16984, 16984, 
16984, 16984, 16984, 16985, 16985, 16985, 16985, 16985, 16985, 
16986, 16986, 16986, 16986, 16986, 16986, 16987, 16987, 16987, 
16987, 16988, 16988, 16988, 16988, 16988, 16989, 16989, 16989, 
16989), class = "Date"), media = c("Newspapers", "Newspapers", 
"Newspapers", "Newspapers", "Magazines", "Magazines", "Magazines", 
"Outdoor", "Outdoor", "Outdoor", "Outdoor", "Outdoor", "Outdoor", 
"Radio", "Radio", "Radio", "Radio", "Radio", "Radio", "Radio", 
"Radio", "Radio", "Radio", "Radio", "Radio", "Radio", "Radio", 
"Radio", "Radio", "Radio", "Radio", "Newspapers", "Magazines", 
"Radio", "Radio", "Radio", "Radio", "Radio", "Radio", "Radio", 
"Radio", "Radio", "Radio", "Radio", "Radio", "Radio", "Newspapers", 
"Newspapers", "Magazines", "Radio"), brand_short = c("Brand A", 
"Brand B", "Brand C", "Brand D", "Brand E", "Brand C", "Brand D", 
"Brand A", "Brand E", "Brand B", "Brand F", "Brand C", "Brand D", 
"Brand A", "Brand E", "Brand B", "Brand F", "Brand C", "Brand D", 
"Brand A", "Brand E", "Brand B", "Brand F", "Brand C", "Brand D", 
"Brand A", "Brand E", "Brand B", "Brand F", "Brand C", "Brand D", 
"Brand C", "Brand E", "Brand A", "Brand E", "Brand F", "Brand C", 
"Brand A", "Brand E", "Brand F", "Brand C", "Brand A", "Brand E", 
"Brand B", "Brand F", "Brand C", "Brand A", "Brand C", "Brand A", 
"Brand A"), label = c("ntv0_Newspapers_Brand A", "ntv0_Newspapers_Brand B", 
"ntv0_Newspapers_Brand C", "ntv0_Newspapers_Brand D", "ntv0_Magazines_Brand E", 
"ntv0_Magazines_Brand C", "ntv0_Magazines_Brand D", "ntv0_Outdoor_Brand A", 
"ntv0_Outdoor_Brand E", "ntv0_Outdoor_Brand B", "ntv0_Outdoor_Brand F", 
"ntv0_Outdoor_Brand C", "ntv0_Outdoor_Brand D", "ntv0_Radio_Brand A", 
"ntv0_Radio_Brand E", "ntv0_Radio_Brand B", "ntv0_Radio_Brand F", 
"ntv0_Radio_Brand C", "ntv0_Radio_Brand D", "ntv0_Radio_Brand A", 
"ntv0_Radio_Brand E", "ntv0_Radio_Brand B", "ntv0_Radio_Brand F", 
"ntv0_Radio_Brand C", "ntv0_Radio_Brand D", "ntv0_Radio_Brand A", 
"ntv0_Radio_Brand E", "ntv0_Radio_Brand B", "ntv0_Radio_Brand F", 
"ntv0_Radio_Brand C", "ntv0_Radio_Brand D", "ntv0_Newspapers_Brand C", 
"ntv0_Magazines_Brand E", "ntv0_Radio_Brand A", "ntv0_Radio_Brand E", 
"ntv0_Radio_Brand F", "ntv0_Radio_Brand C", "ntv0_Radio_Brand A", 
"ntv0_Radio_Brand E", "ntv0_Radio_Brand F", "ntv0_Radio_Brand C", 
"ntv0_Radio_Brand A", "ntv0_Radio_Brand E", "ntv0_Radio_Brand B", 
"ntv0_Radio_Brand F", "ntv0_Radio_Brand C", "ntv0_Newspapers_Brand A", 
"ntv0_Newspapers_Brand C", "ntv0_Magazines_Brand A", "ntv0_Radio_Brand A"
), var1 = c(2, 3, 2, 1, 6, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 451, 6, 468, 
921, 800, 258, 36, 14, 546, 1316, 749, 264, 36, 15, 608, 918, 
1097, 265, 1, 1, 25, 4, 3, 1129, 25, 4, 3, 981, 46, 5, 552, 4, 
989, 1, 1, 1, 65), var2 = c(9240, 41030, 146280, 45000, 792500, 
151900, 115483, 302125, 4034, 555326, 2661, 5806, 48268, 473789, 
60340, 237996, 484655, 415685, 338373, 6185, 39760, 149848, 315474, 
210416, 159881, 5577, 24150, 100646, 174513, 317148, 106100, 
98280, 164450, 3730, 17990, 160, 941389, 3726, 18060, 152, 765857, 
14152, 34790, 354024, 862, 872216, 6240, 16450, 1870, 20458)), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -50L))
```

I want to have rows for all combinations of `data`, `media` and `brand_short` filling `var1` and `var2` with `0` if a combination was absent in data. I also would like to preserve `label` variable, which - as you can notice - is created using `media` and `brand_short`. I know there's `tidyr::complete` function designed specifically for that, but I'm having troubles with appropriate call. The one I have tried:

```
ex %>% complete(data, nesting(media, brand_short, label), fill = list(var1 = 0, var2 = 0))
```

doesn't produce for all brands or produce additional, unwanted labels:

```
ex %>% complete(data, media, nesting(brand_short, label), fill = list(var1 = 0, var2 = 0))
```

How can I make my data frame to have for any specific date all `media` and `brand_short` combinations (so 24 rows for every date), but not combining with `label`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're overthinking it. You don't need to nest anything because you want all possible combinations of `data`,`media` and `brand_short`. `label` should not be included. To update the label, use a `mutate` statement afterwards.

```
ex %>% complete(data,media,brand_short,fill=list(var1=0,var2=0)) %>%
mutate(label=paste('ntv0',media,brand_short,sep='_'))
# A tibble: 168 x 6
   data       media      brand_short label                    var1   var2
   <date>     <chr>      <chr>       <chr>                   <dbl>  <dbl>
 1 2016-07-01 Magazines  Brand A     ntv0_Magazines_Brand A      0      0
 2 2016-07-01 Magazines  Brand B     ntv0_Magazines_Brand B      0      0
 3 2016-07-01 Magazines  Brand C     ntv0_Magazines_Brand C      1 151900
 4 2016-07-01 Magazines  Brand D     ntv0_Magazines_Brand D      2 115483
 5 2016-07-01 Magazines  Brand E     ntv0_Magazines_Brand E      6 792500
 6 2016-07-01 Magazines  Brand F     ntv0_Magazines_Brand F      0      0
 7 2016-07-01 Newspapers Brand A     ntv0_Newspapers_Brand A     2   9240
 8 2016-07-01 Newspapers Brand B     ntv0_Newspapers_Brand B     3  41030
 9 2016-07-01 Newspapers Brand C     ntv0_Newspapers_Brand C     2 146280
10 2016-07-01 Newspapers Brand D     ntv0_Newspapers_Brand D     1  45000
# ... with 158 more rows
```